# Springboot thymeleaf working with multiple pagination for two different result tables in one page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, pagination, thymeleaf

Following sample code work well for `Table1` pagination. But I have to display another `Table2` result data with pagination.

Controller (Fetch data from service and pass result to model)

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/main", "/" })
    public ModelAndView init(ModelAndView mav, Locale locale, @PageableDefault(size = 10, page = 0) Pageable pageable, HttpServletRequest request) {
        
        mav.setViewName("mian/main");
        try {
            // get data from service
            Page<Entity1> table1Data = null;
            // url setup
            String url = "?";
            PageWrapper<Entity1> table1 = new PageWrapper<Entity1>(table1Data, url);
            mav.addObject("page1", table1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return mav;
        }
        return mav;
    }
```

html (just displaying `page1` content here)

```
<form id="mainForm" th:action="@{/main}" method="get" th:object="${form}">
        <div class="row">
            Table 1
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-nowrap" scope="col">Type1</th>
                        <th class="text-nowrap" scope="col">Message1</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr th:each="page: ${page1.content}">
                    <td>
                        <span th:text="${page.type}"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p th:text="${page.message}"></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <!-- pagination -->
        <div th:if='${page1.totalPages ge 1}'>
            <div>
                <nav aria-label="...">
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <li>
                            <a th:if='${not page.firstPage}' th:href="@{${page.url}(page=0,size=${page.size})}"><span
                                    aria-hidden="true">&lt;&lt;</span></a>
                            <a>...</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a>...</a>
                        </li>

                        <li th:each='item : ${page1.items}'>
                            <a th:href='@{${page1.url}(page=${item.number-1},size=${page1.size})}'><span
                                    th:text='${item.number}'>1</span></a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a th:if='${page1.hasNextPage}'><span aria-hidden="true">&gt;</span></a>
                            <a>...</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a>...</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <span>rowsPerPage</span>
                    <div>
                        <select th:field="${page1.size}" class="form-control" onchange="changepageSize();">
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

javaScript

```
function changePageSize(){
    $("#mainForm").submit();
};
```

So, I tried to add `table2Data` in model and display it in html as following.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/main", "/" })
    public ModelAndView init(ModelAndView mav, Locale locale, @PageableDefault(size = 10, page = 0) Pageable pageable, HttpServletRequest request) {
        
        mav.setViewName("mian/main");
        try {
            // get data from service
            Page<Entity1> table1Data = null;
            Page<Entity2> table2Data = null;
            // url setup
            String url = "?";
            PageWrapper<Entity1> table1 = new PageWrapper<Entity1>(table1Data, url);
            PageWrapper<Entity2> table2 = new PageWrapper<Entity2>(table2Data, url);
            mav.addObject("page1", table1);
            mav.addObject("page2", table2);
    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return mav;
        }
        return mav;
    }
```

html

```
<form id="mainForm" th:action="@{/main}" method="get" th:object="${form}">

        <div class="row">
            Table 1
             <!-- pagination -->
             .....
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            Table 2
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-nowrap" scope="col">Type2</th>
                        <th class="text-nowrap" scope="col">Message2</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr th:each="page: ${page2.content}">
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <!-- pagination -->
        <div th:if='${page2.totalPages ge 1}'>
            <div>
                <nav aria-label="..."></nav>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <span>rowsPerPage</span>
                    <div>
                        <select th:field="${page2.size}" class="form-control" onchange="changepageSize();">
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                            <option value="100">100</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Literally, I just duplicate `table1'`s code. (just display is fine) Of course it doesn't work when I tried to change either table1 or table2. As I passed one `Pageable`, when I tried to change one table another table will be change too.

Can I get any advice for working with multiple pagination?
Any idea is welcome!